# How send List<String> as Object and read it using ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, list, object, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I have server and client and I wanna from sendMsg(Object obj) send Objects to server: the first is custom Class Message(Message class is serializable), the second is String and the last is List.
When I try reading List - the server does nothing(no errors). The debugger says (The application is running), then I send Message object the client loose connection because the server doesn't respond.
Here is client side:

```
public static synchronized boolean sendMsg(Object obj) {
        try {
            if (socket == null || socket.isClosed()) {
                launch();
                return false;
            } else {
                objOutStream.writeObject(obj);
                objOutStream.flush();
                return true;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Outputstream not found.");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here is server side:

```
public synchronized void readMessages() throws IOException {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Object obj = objInputStream.readObject();
                if (obj != null) {
                    if (obj.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Message")) {
                        server.chooseClientForMessage((Message) obj, this);
                        break;
                    }
                    if (obj.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("List<String>")) {
                        sendMessage(server.getOnlineClients((List<String>) obj));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "the server doesn't respond" yes, you have an infinite loop.

Comment: then, `simpleName` for a class is never going to be  `"List<String>"`. It would simply be `"List"`

Comment: I recommend you look into a debugger on the server side what actual class you receive

Comment: Why, specifically, do you want to do that? Life is much easier if you send JSON instead.

Comment: @njzk2 Debugger doesnt cheks line after  `Object obj = objInputStream.readObject(); ` and listen this line. When I push Next step - server falls with Runtime exeption.

Comment: what is the exact exception and the message?